# How to connect to these terminal blocks?

Tags: wiring

I have this power supply (actually part of a control box for a robot arm) which has terminal blocks, but most of the screws seem complete inaccessible due to how closely the blocks are placed together. Here is a picture of the one semi-reachable screw in the whole device.

[image: a reachable screw among unreachable screws]

Here is a top view of where I want my wires to go in.
[image: top view]

I thought maybe the connection pads were spring loaded but I could not pry them open with a tweezer.

Taking a picture from one side, I noticed there is a label! "DORABO DB2EK-3.5"
[image: label on the block]

Comment: Is there a chance the top section of the block disengages by pulling upward?  Some of these types of blocks are on large pull-away pins/sockets, (but not all).  For e.g. see : https://www.amazon.com/OIIKI-Terminal-Straight-Connector-Pluggable/dp/B08GP4BMD3/ref=asc_df_B08GP4BMD3/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=564776365877&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18408958232811548301&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9003607&hvtargid=pla-1402736091834&mcid=94c8ebb1c22e3bccb8025c41c353630a&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpfS9nqX8gwMVTEtHAR2fSAzcEAQYByABEgJBkfD_BwE&th=1

Comment: I did think about that and tried tugging on it but it didn't come off easily so I got scared to pull harder. Maybe it's time to get in touch with the manufacturer. I'll report back.

Comment: Additional photos of the sides and edges of the blocks might give someone a better hint on how it is to be used.  Some versions also have locking tabs or small screws holding the sections together.

Comment: Wow great advice! There was a label and I found it here https://www.nbdibo.com/product/lifting-terminal-block/pcb-plug-in-connector-db2ek-3-5.html

I think it is the "plug in" type that you had guessed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a [Dorabo terminal block PDF](https://www.nbdibo.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/DB2EK-3.5-XXP-C-S.pdf) close to the P/N that you have. It is the top half of the terminal block assembly. As you can see there are also key guides that help locate and seat the halves.

Not sure if there is a locking tab that first needs to be disengaged.
You might try prying very carefully at the first plastic to plastic interface above the PCB surface to separate the two sections. Once separated you would loosen the terminal screw, insert the wire, re-tighten the screw, repeat for all other wires on that terminal block, then reinsert the upper block into the lower section.

Comment: But these blocks are so close together it is impossible to fit a screw driver between them. Unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mark These are industry standard pluggable "Eurostyle" terminal blocks: the whole terminal plugs into a header in the equipment.  I am certain the black plastic block can simply be pulled out (or levered gently, prying against the equipment face) from the headers they plug into.

Comment: @Mark - Look for the the interface between the two sections from the side that you took the photo of. Perhaps the dividing line is part way up the side.  If you grab it at the top corners of the long edges you may be able to rock it back and forth until you see it begin to separate.